# Feeling insecure about my job

Tags: work-environment, work-experience

I started working as a developer for a new company. I started at this company 2 months ago. I worked different companies before as a developer, but I didn't feel this insecure.
My colleagues' code is really good. When I can, I replicate them but I want to know how can I be at that level. By the way I am coding in java for the last 3 years. But maybe they have been writing for more than 5-6 years of java.

My question is how to be as good as them. How to overcome this feeling, or is this feeling good. Just need some advice on this issue. If you felt like this before I want to know how did you overcome.

Comment: SS YY KK, welcome to the workplace. What is your question?

Comment: Related over at Academia on [Imposter Syndrome](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11765/ive-somehow-convinced-everyone-that-im-actually-good-at-this-how-to-effect)

Comment: As an aside... if you can use one (or more) of these developers as a mentor to improve your skills, this is actually a very enviable place to be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to get as good as them is to learn, gain experience, and never be afraid to ask questions.

You're the junior in a team of more experienced people, and they no doubt know that and expect you to not be up to their level yet.

But they will also expect you to progress and get better over time. Study, ask questions if there's things you don't understand and can't find answers to yourself in reasonable time, take advise from others, don't be that guy who's convinced he has nothing to learn (NEVER be that guy, even if you've decades of experience and are the highest educated person in the company).

Your coworkers got to where they are that way, and if they're any good will realise that you need time and guidance/coaching to get there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to learn is by doing. You can also get books in the area such as Code Complete (which is a fantastic general software development beat practices guide) and other domain specific books.

It is a good idea to not only do the research yourself but to let your  senior colleagues and managers know that you are interested in improving yourself. Ask them for book recommendations. This probably won't cost much as most companies will have a library of books built up over time.

Also ask for code reviews of your work and take any suggested improvements in board. If you don't know what you're doing wrong you can't get better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for you this feeling is at first probably bad.

However, I think it is positive in the sense that it will (at least should) force you to re-evaluate your own skills and enhance your knowledge in the process to become more secure in your profession.

Obviously experience and routine will over the years do a similar thing.

As for how to become good, I believe previous answers will help you there.